# How to mimic or achieve IS-A relationships for Kotlin data classes

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I have been exploring Kotlin and have written a small program/script that does a task I find boring.

In the development of the program I use data classes to represent a Playlist. at one point in the design I wanted to have a special type of `Playlist` that was `EmptyPlaylist`.

I couldn't get this to work.

How would you achieve this relationship with Kotlin?

In Java, I would just extend `Playlist` (or perhaps create an interface/abstract class for them both to inherit from).

I just wanted to be able to have a `List<Playlist>` rather than `List<Playlist?>`

In the end I just created a `Playlist` object, but I am interested in if it is possible to create IS-A hierarchies with data classes.

Comment: It would be good to show your attempt at the code (or equivalent in Java you wanted ), for future questions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPD: Kotlin Beta added restrictions on `data` classes, so the answer has also been updated.

> - Data classes cannot be abstract, open, sealed or inner;
> - Data classes may not extend other classes (but may implement interfaces).

So the only option for building their hierarchies is interfaces. This restriction may be released in future versions.

---

The idea of inheriting `EmptyPlaylist` from `Playlist` which is presumed non-empty according to your words looks a little bit contradictory, but there are options:

- You can make both `TracksPlaylist` and `EmptyPlaylist` implement some `Playlist` interface. This is reasonable because `EmptyPlaylist` may not contain everything that a `Playlist` does. This would look like:

  ```
  public interface Playlist

  data class TracksPlaylist(val name: String, val tracks: List<Track>) : Playlist
  data class EmptyPlaylist(val name: String): Playlist
  ```
- If you don't want multiple instances of `EmptyPlaylist` to even exist, you can make it a `val` instead of distinct class and avoid is-checks, just comparing to

  ```
  val EMPTY_PLAYLIST = TracksPlaylist("EMPTY", listOf())
  ```

  This is applicable when *empty playlists* are all equal so that a single object is sufficient to represent them all.
- You can use [`sealed` classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#sealed-classes). This doesn't allow you to use `data` classes, but `sealed` classes may fit for building class hierarchies like this.

  `sealed` class is an abstract class which can only have its subclasses be declared inside its body. This gives the compiler guarantees that these are the only subclasses. Example:

  ```
  sealed class Playlist(val name: String) {
      class Tracks(name: String, val tracks: List<Track>): Playlist(name)
      class Playlists(name: String, val innerPlaylists: List<Playlist>): Playlist(name)
      object Empty: Playlist("EMPTY")
  }
  ```

  After that, you will be able to use `when` statement without specifying `else` branch if you state all the subclasses and objects of the sealed class:

  ```
  when (p) {
      is Playlist.Tracks -> { /* ... */ }
      is Playlist.Playlists -> { /* ... */ }
      Playlist.Empty -> { /* ... */ }
  }
  ```

  However, this option requires you to deal with `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString`, `copy` and `componentN` on your own, if you need them.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I was confused as the wisdom of the net suggested that extending data classes was problematic.  I hadn't thought about extending an abstract class, which to be fair is pretty dumb of me, I should have seen that option.
Of all the options I like the last one!
Reading between the lines you can extend data class just as you would a normal class?

Comment: Yeah the "design" is a little contradictory, as it has evolved; initially it was just to deal with one playlist file and learning Kotlin.  As I have enjoyed using Kotlin more and wanted to do more with the script its just grown in functionality if not so much in lines of code. 
Normally i wouldn't extend EmptyPlaylist from Playlist :)

Comment: @Gavin, yes, `data` class inheritance is limited: you can't define new properties in the primary constructor nor override `componentN` functions, and you'll probably have to override `equals` and `hashCode` (which is another pain in the neck when working with class hierarchy) in both parent and child classes. But it's possible if you just add new properties and functions in class body and don't expect them to be automatically used by `data` under-the-hood code.

Comment: ah thanks for clearing that up.  I think it would have worked for my purposes.

Comment: Updated the answer so that it's up-to-date with Kotlin restrictions on data classes.